# Hate people touching or using his things

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, psychology, personification

What do we call a person who don't share his or her personal belongings or things with others? or hate people touching his things

Comment: This is more a question about [psychology](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) than English.

Comment: Though this word doesn't specifically address what you outlined, the person you're describing is probably a `germophobe`.

Comment: It depends entirely on *why* the person objects to others touching their things. (*Protective*, *embarrassed*, *private*?)

Answer (score 1):

**Possessive** seems like the best option. See sense 3 [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/possessive#Adjective):

> Unwilling to yield possession of.

Or more explicitly [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/possessive):

> If you are possessive about something that you own, you do not like lending it to other people or sharing it with other people

Answer (score 0):

I think the name/phrase you want is ***dog in a manger***.

So, when someone is not sharing something they have you can say

> "Don't be such a dog in a manger!"

From an old [Greek fable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dog_in_the_Manger), apparently!